# Using sed to delete a pattern from the line

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a list.txt file that contains a list of file paths:

```
/old/file/path/directory
/old/file/path/mydirectory
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
/path/directory
/path/mydirectory
```

to do this, I am using *sed*:

```
OLDPATH=/old/file/


sed "\|$OLDPATH|d" list.txt > newlist.txt
```

However this deletes the line completely. How do I delete the part I want only using `sed` and the variable `$OLDPATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you can use this syntax:

```
OLDPATH="/old/file"
sed "s#$OLDPATH##" list.txt > newlist.txt
```

This looks for `$OLDPATH` and removes it, whereas your `|d` removes the lines containing the pattern given.

With your given input data it returns:

```
/path/directory
/path/mydirectory
```

Comment: Just for my info, from now on if I want to delete a pattern in a line I would be better off using 's#PATTERN##', is that correct?

Comment: @user2617731 exactly. There general substitution pattern is: `sed "s/something/replacement/"`. So if you leave `replacement` empty, this `something` is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If all your lines start with `OLDPATH`, you can use

```
cut -c $(echo -n "$OLDPATH" | wc -c)-
```

or better yet:

```
cut -c "$((${#OLDPATH}+1))"-
```